# How to use adb over Mobile AP (Portable wifi hotspot)

Tags: android, wifi, adb

First : I know about abdWireless app. But my problem is different.

I am using my Android mobile as Mobile AP (Portable WiFi hotspot) for using internet on my computer. I want to use adb in wireless mode but the problem is - when i enable `Mobile AP` on my android mobile WiFi gets turned off and i am unable to use abdWireless app.

I want to use both `wireless ADB` and `Mobile AP` at the same time. 
Is there any way to do it ???

Comment: It may also be helpful to ask this on http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 4):

Developers have created apps for this:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb
```

Once you start this app, you can connect to your phone like this:

```
adb connect ip_address_of_the_device
```

However, your phone must be rooted!

Please let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

On mac:
You need to run: `ifconfig`

[image]

Followed by run: `arp -a`

[image]

In my case, the first listed IP is router IP, ie. IP of your android device with hotspot(let it be: ip_address_of_the_hotspot_device).

Then run either: `adb connect ip_address_of_the_hotspot_device` or `adb connect ip_address_of_the_hotspot_device:5555`

Answer (score 0):

Run following command by connecting usb:

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

the for ip address use following command:

```
 arp -a
```

you will get **ip_address** address of device.Then use following command to connect

```
adb connect ip_address_:555
```

Now you can remove USB cable.